# Merging Config library

Tags: java, scala, playframework, typesafe, typesafe-config

Is there anyway to merge two config files the following way:

```
val conf1= ....
val conf2= ....
conf1.withFallbackToPath(conf2,"root.branch2")

**conf1.conf**
root {
   branch1 {
      value="Hello i am source"
   }
}

**conf2.conf**
value = "I am merged"
```

The result of this merge should be :

```
root {
   branch1 {
      value="Hello i am source"
   }
   branch2 {
      value = "I am merged"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

conf2.atPath("root.branch2").withFallback(conf1)